# Do I need rails asset folder under asssets after precompiling assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets

I have compiled assets using following command in rails 3.2 for production purpose.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

After running above command an assets a folder is created under public. Now I want to removed non-compile assets folder because it is huge. But I have need answers to following questions.

- Do I need the assets folder that contains non-compiled assets ?
- If yes then what is purpose of having a non-compiled assets folder ?

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, keep them.

The purpose is that when they are taken from assets to public they are usually minified and combined, greatly saving space and helping to reduce download time for end users when using the site.  But when you need to make changes, use the originals in assets.

In development mode (local, on your box), the assets version is used and is useful in traces while developing/debugging as they point to the actual source code lines in question and have the original (usually longer and meaningful) variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you will need to make changes to one of your assets in `app/assets` in the future.
`app/assets` has the original source files with original formatting and these are the files you should change.

Theoretically you could delete the source files in app/assets, but then you won't be able to change anything and re-compile with those changes.